# 'Error #2006: Supplied index out of bounds' when invoking RPC service

Tags: apache-flex

I've got to invoke a RPC service, and all the parameters sent are String. It works quite well when the data is relatively small, but when one of the string grows to the size about 10 or over hundred KB, immediately after the service is invoked, it goes to the error handler:

[FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds." faultCode="InvokeFailed" faultDetail="null"] messageId="85CF2FB3-E79D-779F-87F9-B04520318D3A" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]

And the server side still got invoked, and when it returns the result, error raised:
Error: Command already finished executing: [object AsyncTokenCommand]

Google says error #2006 may because of too many hierarchy levels, which seems impossible to me because all my parameters are string. And I also don't have the chance to mistake on index.

I first thought it was because the string sent is too long, I segmented it and sent in a list, but didn't work.

Thanks in advance if you guys can give any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it right. 
It was because I turned on the Network Monitor in Flash Builder.
Everything OK after it's off.

Comment: A very old answer, but this solved a problem I was having with a web service when sending a byte[]. Thank you.